# How to use a string in join of MySQL without using "IN"

Tags: php, mysql

I have an variable of order ids like:

```
$OrderIds = "1,2,3,4,5,6"; //thousands of ids
```

I want to use this string with MySQL join, without using "IN" statement because "IN" statement take much time to execute and I think "IN" statement is not good for that kind of things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with the `IN` clause. the columns which you're using might be scanning full table. Create an `index` on the column if the column is not `primary_key` or indexed. Then your query will work faster.

Comment: Questions asking to improve performance should include more information. What is the actual query? Definition (CREATE statement) for the involved tables. How many rows in the table? How many ids in the IN clause? What is EXPLAIN saying?

Comment: When you say, "I think", that does not mean much. Querying with IN is the best approach, as far as I know, to query several values of the same field. If you can provide documental proof of your statement, please do in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use IN you can use UNION:

```
$sql=""
$OrderIds=explode(',',$OrderIds);
for($i=0;$i++;$i<count($OrderIds)){
   $where.=" SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE orderId=".$OrderIds[$i]; //quote the id
   if($i<count($OrderIds)-1) $where.=" UNION ";
}
$db->query($sql);
```

But I would use IN!

Comment: Yeah, this wont by faster. Even if you might save some performance regarding the IN, you'll loose it in the php loop

Comment: Ok, but I'm just answering: how we can use a string in join of mysql without using “IN”

Comment: Internally IN statement might be work as same by using OR but it will be very slow

Comment: You are right but i want to find best way to do it because by this method our query execution time is slow because i have more than 1000 order ids. According to my experience i realize that IN and OR is usefull in case of limited no. of order ids like 10-20.And we have more than 1000000 rows in table.. that's why i am not want to use this method

Comment: Thank you Tobia !!